# HIVE:I cannot drop the view

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to drop the duplicate views, but I get this error.The tables are in parquet format.
query: drop view esquema.tabla

**This is the error.**
SQL Error [1] [08S01]: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:380)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:257)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$800(SQLOperation.java:91)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:348)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1889)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:362)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.dropTable(Hive.java:1200)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.dropTable(Hive.java:1131)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.dropTable(DDLTask.java:4176)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.dropTableOrPartitions(DDLTask.java:4038)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:379)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:199)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2183)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1839)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1232)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:255)
... 11 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newMetaException(HiveMetaStore.java:6143)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.drop_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStore.java:1932)`enter code here`
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor409.invoke(Unknown Source)